# How to get the group_id from the "groups_join_group" action in buddypress

Tags: buddypress, actions

I want to get the GROUP_creator_id when an user joins any GROUP. So if I got the `group_id` after immediately performing the the `groups_join_group` action by `add_action()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$group_id` is the first argument passed to `groups_join_group` action hook function, the second argument is `$user_id`. You can use these data to obtain group `creator_id` like:

```
add_action('groups_join_group', 'my_groups_join_group_action', 10, 2);

function my_groups_join_group_action($group_id, $user_id) {
    // use $group_id and $user_id here:
    $group = groups_get_group( array( 'group_id' => $group_id ) );
    $creator_id = $group->creator_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bundle :) Its worked like a charm :) Thanks again and again